# Highcharts spider chart intersect issue

Tags: highcharts

How can I make sure that the values on the x-axis intersect the y-axis.
When I use categories on the yAxis there seems to be a weird offset which causes the axis going out of the boundaries.

It didn't work with setting the `startOnTick: true` and the `endOnTick: true` properties.

JS fiddle with categories on y-axis
http://jsfiddle.net/m8h0wLq4/13/

JS fiddle without categories on y-axis
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/

Comment: So, what is issue and what you want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `tickmarkPlacement: 'on'` for your yAxis:

```
yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    pointInterval : 1,
    min: 0,
    max : 4,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    categories: ['Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced', 'Expert']
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8h0wLq4/14/